# How can I force the position of a float that I created the environment for using newfloat?

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a stubborn float that won't appear in the right page (even though there is really no reason for that -- it takes a whole page, and for some reason it appears after the end of the chapter, though it could be inserted right where I ask it to, since it is a whole page float).

Unfortunately, I can't use H with the package float, since it is my own new float environment.

Here is what I tried (and got an error with):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}



\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of A,
    name=FloatA,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floata}


\begin{document}

\begin{floata}[Ht]
\caption[float a]{float a example}
\end{floata}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`H` if used has to be used on its own it makes no sense to combine with the float options as the meaning of `H` is to make the environment not a float.
Note that if you did not use `H` you would want `p` as omitting `p` forces latex not to use a float page, which for a large float is normally what is needed.  If you do not give latex any legal position to place the float it will be held back until flushed out by `\clearpage` typically at the end of a chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}



\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=loa,
    listname=List of A,
    name=FloatA,
    placement=tbhp,
    within=chapter,
]{floata}


\begin{document}

\begin{floata}[H]
\caption[float a]{float a example}
\end{floata}


\end{document}
```